# Python print messed up after calling curses wrapper

Tags: python, printing, curses

I am having a problem with curses library in Python. Consider the following code:

```
def main(stdscr):

    print('Hello World!!')
    create_screen()
    curses.endwin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

The problem is every text printed by "print" function is messed up even before calling "create_screen()" function which initiates the screen by "curses.initscr()"

Comment: Then do not print anything... you're using curses for a reason.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Why can't you use `curses` for those "normal" calls to `print`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I need to print some stuff before calling main program screen by curses, like, banner and user input

Comment: @tobias_k I am trying to get a user input which will specify if I will invoke program main screen by curses or not, in addition to that i am printing program banner

Comment: What happens if you do those `print` and `input` _before_ calling `curses.wrapper`?

Comment: @tobias_k It worked fine, but the problem is I need to call main function through Wrapper in order to restore the terminal to its original state whenever any exception raised during program execution

Comment: @Lonesome I don't see what's the problem with that. The "main" function is nothing special. You can pass any other function to the curses wrapper, or put print and input statements and error handling stuff outside of the main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print` and `input` normally before and after your program uses `curses`. Also, you do not have to put all your code into `main`, and you don't have to pass the `main` function to `curses`, either. `main` is just a function like any other. Check out this simple example:

```
import curses, time

def incurses(stdscr):
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Exiting in ")
    stdscr.addstr(2, 0, "Hello World from Curses!")
    for i in range(5, -1, -1):
        stdscr.addstr(0, 11, str(i))
        stdscr.refresh()
        time.sleep(1)
    curses.endwin()

def main():
    print('Hello World!!')
    choice = input("Start Curses Program? ")
    if choice == "yes":
        curses.wrapper(incurses)
    print("After curses")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This prints and asks for user input, then shows a curses screen, then goes back into "normal" printing mode.

Comment: Thank you so much @tobias_k  that is the problem with over thinking :)

Comment: `curses.endwin()` is not required as `curses.wrapper` does it automatically. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#starting-and-ending-a-curses-application